# cleaning the files in directory in linux

Tags: c, linux

I want to clean all files in a directory on Linux (not deleteing them, only clear their content)

I need to do it in C.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you really *don't* need to do it in C. UNIX includes tools that can just about do *any* task that you want.

```
find . -type f -exec cp /dev/null {} ';'
```

That particular snippet above will find all files under the current directory and attempt to copy the null device to it, effectively truncating the file to 0 bytes.

You can change the starting (top level) directory, restrict names (with `-name '*.jpg'` for example) and even restrict it to the current directory (no subdirectories) with `-maxdepth 0`.

There are *many* other options with `find` that you can discover by entering `man find` into your command line shell. Just don't enter it into Google, you may get more than you bargained for :-)

---

If the need to use C is an absolutely non-negotiable one, I would *still* do it this way but with:

```
system ("find . -type f -exec cp /dev/null {} ';'");
```

I'm not keen on re-writing software that someone's already put a bucketload of effort into providing for free :-)

---

If, after my advice, you *still* want to do it the hard way, you need to look into [`opendir`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_opendir.htm), [`readdir`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_readdir.htm) and [`closedir`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_closedir.htm) for processing directories, then just use [`fopen`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_fopen.htm) in write mode followed by [`fclose`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_fclose.htm) on each candidate file.

If you want to navigate whole directory structures rather than just the current directory, you'll have to detect directories from `readdir` and probably recurse through them.

Comment: Then, seriously, use `system ("find . -type f -exec cp /dev/null {} ';'");`. There's rarely a good reason to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: you can also use `truncate(filename, 0)` instead of opening/closing the file

Comment: Seriously don't use `system()` just because you're in a hurry.  Find the cross-platform standard way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @meager, the question was tagged linux, hence cross-platform is a YAGNI requirement. In any case, ISO C itself doesn't provide a standard way of doing this but you can turn to POSIX, which is why I gave that as an option.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash:

```
for i in directory/*; do > $i; done
```

This will preserve ownership and permissions of the file.

***Don't do shell work in C!*** Save a huge amount of time by using the best tool for the job. If this is homework, mark it as such.

Comment: btw, you don't need to run echo, `do > $i; done` works just as well

Answer (score 3):

- `scandir` to list them, then for every file:
- `fopen(, w+)`
- `fstat` to get the size
- `fwrite` the whole file with zeroes? (this is what you mean by clear?)
- `fclose`

A nice shell variant would be: `shred -z directory/*`

Comment: Just `scandir()` followed by a `truncate(filename, 0)` on each file will do the trick.

Comment: Well... depends, if you want to make it hard(er) to recover, then writing data in place is sane. Otherwise yes, just `truncate()`, or more standard conforming `fopen(file, "w")+fclose()` will do the trick.

Comment: It won't make a difference with the advent of copy-on-write filesystems, though ;)

Comment: caf, please explain why COW is relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file in write mode and then close it.

Comment: how i get all the files in the directory in C